# How to Restrict Submit Order for unavailable products from magento backend

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

Magento frontend not allowed to process the order if cart contains either out of stock product or unavailable product.

But When I create an order from Magento admin then How to Restrict Submit Order for unavailable products.

For example, I create a order from admin and add two products in the cart, one is out of stock and for second 2 qty not available in stock.
But Submit order button not disabled there, When I click on submit order Magento placed an order. Due to this inventory is disturbing.

Below image describe my case :

[image]

How to disable Submit Order button if cart contains either out of stock product or unavailable product?

Comment: Hi @VinayaMaheshwari did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I did not have any solution yet